# Logs partly lost after crash

Tags: logs, crash, systemd-journald, journalctl

I am trying to fix an issue with PM (suspend) on my laptop,
therefore I enabled some logging for my kernel (`pm_debug_messages`) to look at it afterwards using `journalctl`.

**The problem is:**
Whenever my system crashes, I lose exactly the interesting last part of it (sometimes even the whole log). Therefore I cannot see what happens.

**My guess:** Maybe it is due to some buffering? Seems like it is not written instantly to the logfile.

How can I convince `journald` to write it instantly?
Or, is there maybe a better way?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `journalctl` keeps logs in RAM only.  To enable persistent storage, do this:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/journal/
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Logs will be kept into `/var/log/journal/` from now on.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. From the  moment on when I run `systemctl suspend`, all the logs are kept back until the system comes online again. If it doesn't those messages are lost

Comment: Depends on how it's configured in your distro. Fedora always writes logs to disk out of the box.